# Issue in CP2102 Breakout module interface with PIC16F877a microcontroller

Tags: pic, cp2102

How to make pin connection between PIC16F877a and CP2102 Breakout module?

below is what i am using now with many pins(confusing).
[image]

what are the pins should connect with the PIC microcontroller for data transfer?
I want to transfer data using UART protocol from my PIC to laptop. I didnt find any answers from google also

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the protocol you can get away with just TXO, RXI, and ground for sending data both ways. DTR and CTS are hardware handshaking lines that your PIC program would have to control and read using additional I/O pins beyond the dedicated PIC UART pins.

TXO is an output and goes to the PIC RX input, RXI is an input and goes to the TX output on the PIC.

If you are not powering the PIC from the USB you should add some series resistors on the data lines (everything but ground and Vcc), something like 1K, to deal with one side being powered and the other not.